# Undefined local variable for `request`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails project I am trying to use the code below, but I am having an issue where I get the following error. `undefined local variable or method 'req'`. I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
require 'net/http'
...
def url_exist?
  url = URI.parse(self.website)
  req.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
  req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  path = url.path if url.path.present?
  req.request_head(path || '/')
  res.code != "404" # false if returns 404 - not found
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  false # false if can't find the server
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order of the second and third lines in the `url_exist?` function. You need to declare a variable before doing anything with it.

```
require 'net/http'
...
def url_exist?
  url = URI.parse(self.website)
  req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  req.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
  # ...
end
```

Also your function is still returning false at the end every time.
[Like before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144710/rails-validations-with-parameters).

Comment: After doing that, I got the following error `the scheme http does not accept registry part` on `eq.request_head(path || '/')` but that may be for another question.

Comment: Yes probably. That is unrelated to the order switch. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156885/checking-url-availability-ruby-on-rails) on stackoverflow may be able to help you with that.

Comment: @SeanCallahan since this solved the issue you were having `undefined local variable or method 'req'` it would be great if you could mark my answer as accepted.